# Firebase: Checking for 'write or delete' for onWrite Events

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following functions that listens to an onWrite event for a database trigger like so:

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}/registered')
        .onWrite(event => {

            ...
         });
```

The above function is called regardless whether the node is deleted or added. How do I check if the onWrite event is a 'delete' event for that particular node, or a 'add' event, such that this function only gets called when it is a 'add' event.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to only trigger this function for an add event, the `onCreate()` trigger would be the way to go.

However, you can also detect if it is an add event inside your `onWrite()` using the `before` and `after` properties of the `Change` object:

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}/registered')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    if (change.before.exists()) {
      //update event
      return null;
    } else if (!change.after.exists()) {
      //delete event
      return null;
    } else {
      //add event
      //do stuff
    }

  });
```

Find more details in the documentation:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data

Comment: Note `exists` is not a function. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67279160/336753

Comment: Also the logic is wrong here. `change.before.exists` could mean both: update or delete.

Answer (score 13):

The `event` that is passed into the function contains both the previous data and the new data for the location that triggered the function. With these two pieces of information, you can deduct whether it was a new write, an update, or a delete.

From the [Firebase documentation for database functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value):

> ```
> exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
> .onWrite(event => {
>   // Only edit data when it is first created.
>   if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
>     return;
>   }
>   // Exit when the data is deleted.
>   if (!event.data.exists()) {
>     return;
>   }
> ```

Comment: Make sure you return null from firebase functions if you dont do any work

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen not working for me getting an error saying ```cannot read property previous of undefined```  how to get rid of it?.

Comment: @KPal The API seems to have changed a lot since 2017 se my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67279160/336753

Answer (score 10):

An onWrite will trigger when a document is created, updated, or deleted. Here's how to check for each of those conditions with Firestore cloud functions.

```
if(event.after.data == undefined){ 
  // Deleted: data before but no data after
  console.log('Deleted');
}

if(event.before.data && event.after.data){ 
  // Updated: data before and data after
  console.log('Update');
}

if(!event.before.data && event.after.data){ 
  // Created: no data before but data after
  console.log('Created');
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect now. `data` is a function so the second option is always true. The `exists` getter should be used instead. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67279160/336753

Answer (score 7):

The API seems to have changed since most of the answers here. Posting version that currently (May 2021) works for me.

Whether it is [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) or [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) in both cases the `onWrite` hook accepts [`change`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions.changejson) object which is just an object holding two document [snapshots](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/c7d67fb749aaf76050c08d29b4c6fca28ec9f5ce/dev/src/document.ts#L99): `before` and `after`.

Creation or Deletion can be detected using the `exists` (which is [getter](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/c7d67fb749aaf76050c08d29b4c6fca28ec9f5ce/dev/src/document.ts#L256) property, not a function).

Also if all you need to handle is creation, better use the [`onCreate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) event handler. It gets just the snapshot of created document in place of the `change` object.

```js
// EITHER
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}/registered')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    // Change contains before and after documents snapshots
    const { before, after } = change;

    // Each snapshot knows if it exists. 
    if (!before.exists) {
      const newEvent = after.data();
      console.log('Event was created', newEvent);
      return;
    }

    if (!after.exists) {
      const oldEvent = before.data();
      console.log('Event was deleted', oldEvent);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Event changed', { from: before.data(), to: after.data() });

  });

// OR
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}/registered')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const newEvent = snapshot.data();
    console.log('Event was created', newEvent); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this updated information. Works perfectly.

Comment: personal hero, thanks for maintaining that question.
On thing remains though, why is nobody checking for the type of the change? Isn't that a possibility more error prone?

Comment: @DerStoffel Well that is the documented API - `change` as the first parameter of `onWrite` callback is a JSON object with `before` and `after` props holding snapshots. The only errors you would be prone to, that I can think of, is a change of the API (which you should pay attention to anyway) or Google messing up the Firebase platform, since it is them who pass the `change` parameter to your callback. We all just choose to trust Google on this.

Comment: but it also says that there is an eventType in the context (type of change).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions.eventcontext#eventtype

I am wondering why the whole net seems to check for the change props instead of that 

Comment: @DerStoffel ah, it wasn't clear you mean the `context.eventType` property. Well I guess it is just simpler this way and gives the same information. If nothing else, checking the `exists` property is universal through rtdb and firestore events. With `eventType` you could introduce error by checking rtdb events in firebase callback or vice versa. Also adding the textual constants for the event types feels just like a lot of code and more space for error. I would use the `context.eventType` for logging though. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: .exists is a method (so much be called with parens), not a getter. See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database.datasnapshot#exists

Answer (score 3):

If your change to Cloud Firestore then it will be :

```
// Only edit data when it is first created.
  if (event.data.previous.exists) {
    return;
  }
  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!event.data.exists) {
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

After reading the following article, adding another check on the event element to the `if-then` statement has some benefits:  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/cloud-functions-realtime-database.html

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database
        .ref("/messages/{messageId}").onWrite(event => {
     if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
        // This is a new message, not a change or a delete.
        // Put code here
    }
})
```

If the read from the database failed (maybe a network error???), then `event.data.previous.exists()` will be false.  The addition of `event.data.exists()` ensures the event element does in fact have data that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

I do this quite a bit in my codebase so I have written a helper you could perhaps use :)

```js
import { Change, firestore } from 'firebase-functions';
import { isNil } from 'lodash';

export enum FirestoreWriteEventType {
  Delete,
  Create,
  Update,
  Unknown
}

/**
 * Returns what type of operation the onWrite was.
 * @param change 
 */
const onWriteHelper = (change: Change<firestore.DocumentSnapshot>): FirestoreWriteEventType => {
  const oldData = change.before.data();

  const newData = change.after.data();

  if (isNil(newData)) {
    return FirestoreWriteEventType.Delete;
  }

  if (oldData && newData) {
    return FirestoreWriteEventType.Update;
  }

  if (!oldData && newData) {
    return FirestoreWriteEventType.Create;
  }

  return FirestoreWriteEventType.Unknown;
};

export default onWriteHelper;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would instead use the .onCreate method which has slightly different syntax but accomplished what you are trying to do. (Note that onWrite and onCreate have both been modified in the jump from <= v0.9.1 to >1.0.0).

Try this:

```js
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}/registered')
        .onCreate((snap, context) => {
          const data = snap.val();
          // ^ the value of the newly inserted data
          // context.params contains all of the wildcard fields used in the document reference.
         });
```